# how to remove dll from visual studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have a large game project in visual studio. There are a bunch of guides online on how to find what dlls your exe loads, such as the visual studio modules tab, and they show that my exe is loading a dll that it shouldn't. How do I find out what code file(s) or setting(s) is causing my project to load that dll so I can fix it? My previous searches only show how to tell WHICH dlls my project loads, and not WHY my project is loading a specific dll.

Comment: There will likely be an import library `.lib` file with the same name as the dll. See where your project links to this `dllbasename.lib` file. And as for removing it are you sure the dll is not needed / used at all?

Comment: Dumpbin.exe /imports is a good way to find implicit dependencies.  Use it on the dll that got loaded before the undesired one.

Comment: I suggest you to try to remove unwanted DLLs in additional dependencies.

Comment: There are just too many reasons why a particular DLL might be loaded to find the cause (particularly on dynamically loaded libraries, e.g. from COM-components). It's probably easier to google for the name of the dll to find the source and then decide whether that's feasible or not (e.g. you can't do anything about parts of the video driver).